# How to format numbers as thousands separator in Flutter and Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need format numbers as thousands separator in flutter and dart on strings as well as numbers.
For this purpose, it is often suggested to use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl), but I prefer to do this with an extension and without using intl package.

For example:
When I have text like: "+2500000.7550", my final output will be delivered as "+2,500,000.7550" and
When I have text like: "5674565544112211", my final output will be delivered as "5674-5655-4411-2211" .

Finally, I want to be able to separate a string variable by a specific character, in a specific pattern (eg. 2-by-2 or 3-by-3 or 4-by-4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this challenge by writing this extension, but if there is a better solution or code , I would appreciate it .

```
extension SubString on String {
  String addSeparator({int? qty = 3, String? separator = ","}) {
    assert(qty! >= 1, "[qty] value as the number separator must be positive!");
    assert(
        separator! != "", "[separator] value as the number separator must not be empty!");
    
     String tempNum=this;
     String sign="";
     String decimal="";


  if(RegExp(r'^[-+]?[0-9](\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)').hasMatch(this)){ 
    if(this[0]=="+"||this[0]=="-"){
    sign=this[0];
    tempNum=this.substring(1);
  }
    if(tempNum.contains(".")){
          decimal="."+tempNum.split(".")[1];
      tempNum=tempNum.split(".")[0];
    }
  }
    
    return sign+(tempNum.split('')
        .reversed
        .join()
        .replaceAllMapped(
            RegExp(r'(.{})(?!$)'.replaceAll('''{}''', '''{$qty}''')),
            (m) => '${m[0]}${separator}')
        .split('')
        .reversed
        .join())+decimal;
  }
}
```

and using it like below code:

```
void main() {
  
  String numberExample = "+4654654.23535";
  
  print('numberExample:  ${numberExample.addSeparator(qty: 3,separator: ",")}');

  String ibanExample= "5674565544112211";
  
  print('ibanExample: ${ibanExample.addSeparator(qty: 4,separator: "-")}'); 

}
```